# Change AVPlayer Volume

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, avplayer, mpvolumeview

So I am streaming a video file with audio using AVPlayer and have a UIWebView overlayed over the video that has controls for play/pause, seek, ect. I also have a slider for volume that I am trying to implement but so far I haven't had any luck. Here is my code the change the volume:

```
- (void)setPlayerVolume:(float)volume
{
    NSArray *tracks = [self.player.currentItem.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    NSMutableArray *audio = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (AVAssetTrack *track in tracks) {
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *input = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
        [input setVolume:volume atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [input setTrackID:track.trackID];
        [audio addObject:input];
    }

    AVMutableAudioMix *mix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    [mix setInputParameters:audio];
    [self.player.currentItem setAudioMix:mix];
}
```

I have been reading up, and it seems like the only solution to use **MPVolumeView**. Are there any other solutions?

Thanks for any help, its greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you overlook the AVPlayer `volume` property? Just set it some float value between 0.0 (mute) and 1.0 (max).

Comment: I am currently building for iOS 6 so I dont have access to that property.